# Call to a member function error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a blog on Laravel 7 and when I try to create a post I get this error:

```
Call to a member function categories() on bool
```

Here is my store method from my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate incoming data
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'categories' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        $data = array();
        $data['title'] = $request->title;
        $data['slug'] = str_slug($request->title);
        $data['user_id'] = Auth::id();
        $data['meta_title'] = $request->meta_title;
        $data['meta_description'] = $request->meta_description;
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $data['body'] = $request->body;
        $data['created_at'] = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

        $slug = str_slug($request->title);
        
        if($image) {
            $image_name = $slug . "-" . date('dmy_H_s_i');
            $ext = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $image_full_name = $image_name . '.' . $ext;

            $upload_path = "public/assets/frontend/uploads/posts/";
            $image_url = $upload_path . $image_full_name;
            $success = $image->move($upload_path, $image_full_name);

            $data['image'] = $image_url;
            $post = DB::table('posts')->insert($data);
            

            $post->categories()->attach($request->categories);
            return redirect(route('admin.posts.index'))->with('successMsg', 'Post has been saved successfully!');
        }
}
```

The laravel error page has a problem with this line:

```
$post->categories()->attach($request->categories);
```

I have a separate table in my database to connect a post id with a category id, it's called category_post
The post content is inserted into the database except the new record in the category_post table

So how do I change that code to work?
Thanks

Comment: Why is everyhing wrapped in `if ($image) {...}`?. This means `$post` will not be saved and there will be no response from server in some cases

Comment: What is the output of `dd($request->categories)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('posts')->insert($data);
```

Returns `true|false` based on successful / failed execution of query. If you want to write like

```
$post->categories()->attach($request->categories);
```

Then you need mode `Post` and create instance like this:

```
$post = new Post;
$post->title = $request->title;
// ...
$post->save();
```

And then you will have instance of `Post` class

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to change only this $post->categories()->attach($request->categories); and not the rest of the code?

Comment: No there is not. This will not create new instance of class `Post`

Comment: Also note that my approach doesn't require `$data` array.

Comment: @PapT if you want to change only that part you can replace `->insert` with `insertGetId` and then do `$post = Post::find($post);` to do a second query to get the model again, though this is quite inefficient